# Is $f(x)=|x-1|^3$ differentiable $\forall x$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Is $f(x)=|x-1|^3$ differentiable $\forall x$?
I can't understand if even if there is no cusp there is still a problem in differentiating it in $x=1$.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you considered the definition of a derivative? What happens when you take the limit in the difference quotient as $x$ approaches 1 from below? Is it the same as if $x$ approaches 1 from above?

Comment: Are we talking real or complex $x$?

Comment: It will turn out that the function is differentiable at $x=1$. But the case $x=1$ has to be treated separately from $x\gt 1$, $x\lt 1$.

Comment: There is no problem because for x> 1, $f(x)= (x- 1)^3$ so has derivative $3(x- 1)^2$ while, for x< 1,, $f(x)= (1- x)^3$ so has derivative $-3(1- x)^2$.   At x= 1, the derivative is $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|h|^3}{h}= \lim_{h\to 0} h^2= 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unpack the definition of the absolute value a bit:
$$
\lvert x \rvert = \begin{cases}
\hfil x, & x \geq 0, \\
-x, & x < 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Then your function can be presented in a similar piecewise form:
$$
f(x) = \lvert x-1 \rvert^3 = \begin{cases}
\hfil (x-1)^3, & x \geq 1, \\
-(x-1)^3, & x < 1.
\end{cases}
$$
This function is clearly differentiable for all $x \neq 1$.  But, at $x=1$, there's a potential problem.  You want to consider the derivative on either side and look at the limits as $x \to 1$.  Notice that we deliberately exclude writing down $f'(1)$ for the moment, since it might not exist.
$$
f'(x) = \begin{cases}
\hfil 3(x-1)^2, & x > 1, \\
-3(x-1)^2, & x < 1.
\end{cases}
$$
So,
$$
\lim_{x \to 1^+} f'(x) = \lim_{x \to 1^+} 3(x-1)^2 = 0
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x \to 1^-} f'(x) = \lim_{x \to 1^-} -3(x-1)^2 = 0
$$
Since, they're equal, we can define
$$
f'(1) = 0
$$
and $f$ is differentiable for all real $x$.

One way to write this back in a single formula is
$$
f'(x) = 3 \lvert x-1 \rvert (x-1)
$$

---

By the way, a similar argument shows that $f$ is twice differentiable (i.e., $f''(x)$ exists for all $x$; in fact you can write $f''(x) = 6\lvert x-1 \rvert$), but that's it.  You can check by looking at limits from the right and left that $f'''(1)$ does not exist.

Comment: (+1) Good details. I guess it isn't so much that we can define $f'(1)$ to be $0$, but by definition it is equal to $0$.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed the function is differentiable at all $x\neq 1$. The possible problem is with $1$.

So, try the definition of the derivative:
$$
f'(x) = \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{f(x) - f(1)}{x-1} = \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\lvert x-1\rvert^3}{x-1}
$$
The function is differentiable at $1$ exactly if this limit exists. So try to check if the left-hand limit and the right-hand limit are the same. For example
$$
\lim_{x \to 1^+} \frac{\lvert x-1\rvert^3}{x-1} = \lim_{x \to 1^+} \frac{(x-1)^3}{x-1} = \dots
$$
And 
$$
\lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{\lvert x-1\rvert^3}{x-1} = \lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{-(x-1)^3}{x-1} = \dots
$$

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not:

$$ \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{|h|^3}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}h^2\operatorname{sgn}(h)=0.$$

It turns out that $f'(x)=3\left|x-1\right|(x-1)$ and $f''(x)=6\left|x-1\right|$ so that $f$ is twice continuously differentiable!